# Is there any way to post multiple image on google plus using ACTION_SEND

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working on an Android App in which I am fetching images from Url. I have to share more than one image on Google+. One image is working fine. Please suggest.
I am using following following peace of code.

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, curentWit.getWit_name());
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(shrd).toString());
                        if(isInLine == 1)
                        {
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris.get(0));
                        }
                        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if GooglePlus lets you send multiple images simultaneously. But if you want to send multiple images at same time(suppose you are emailing) then you should make use of `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` instead of `Intent.ACTION_SEND`

This is how I sent multiple images via email.

```
Intent shareIntent = null;

if(uris.size > 1) {
    shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
}
else {
    if (uris.size() == 1) {
        shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris.get(0));
    }
}
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, curentWit.getWit_name());
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(shrd).toString());

startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: Apurva one more question about gridview.can we customised gridview with auto adjust columns according to width of columns

Comment: @VinayakMishra yes, you can adjust the width of gridview columns.

Comment: mean if in  first row two item next row three item as it can be show

Comment: @VinayakMishra you should use `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` attribute in `<GridView>` it will adjust as many elements as possible in every row.

Comment: can you come at another question i am going to post.